# Can we have more than one arbiter in monogodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am setting up cluster of my webserver which uses mongodb. I am doing replica set of mongodb.I have only two machines. So can I have two arbiters in replica set ?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are saying. You need at-least 3 machines on which 1 can be arbiter, not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need in having 2 arbiters.

The minimum recommended replica set consists of THREE servers and is:

- a primary
- a secondary
- an arbiter

the arbiter can be on either machines, but it is recommended to be on a separate machine (VM or anything) so that it won't go down with one of the servers if something goes wrong.

You could use multiple arbiters but if you have only two machines, it will do you no good because you always need n/2 + 1 servers for a succesful election.

Comment: And if the instance the sole arbiter is on goes down?  You now have only the primary and secondary, and as I understand it you can no longer have a successful election.  This is how I ended up on this page, trying to figure out how you add redundancy wrt arbiters.

Comment: If only the arbiter goes down, there is no need for an election, since the primary node is still active. The case you describe is when the primary and the arbitrary are off. This case requires a manual intervention.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not saying you need an election _because_ the arbiter goes down.  I'm saying that if it does and an election becomes necessary for some reason, it won't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple arbiters, in theory, could be useful to increase HA, as a single arbiter is an actual Single Point of Failure (SPoF). But I believe you are correct, that having even number arbiters and even number members of a replica set would still end up in a tie for primary.

I am working on providing HA for arbiter by setting up Keepalived/Virtual IP so if one arbiter goes down, the other will take over. I registered the VIP DNS as the arbiter via mongo shell.

Comment: An arbiter is not really a single point of failure: it is a voting-only node and a replica set should have either 0 arbiters (with an odd number of data-bearing voting members) or 1 arbiter (with an even number of data-bearing voting members). An arbiter votes in elections and helps with one form of availability (maintaining a voting quorum) but cannot contribute to write availability. Setting up an arbiter with Keepalived/VirtualIP avoids deciding where to place your arbiter if you want to limit a deployment to two data centres, but risks a netsplit which can accidentally allow two primaries.

Comment: @Stennie how is it *not* a SPoF?  If you have two data nodes and an arbiter, what happens after the arbiter goes down if an election is required?

Comment: @Madbreaks The arbiter is a voting-only node that does not have any special role in the election process. A three member replica set can elect a primary as long as there are two healthy voting nodes (since a strict majority requires 2/3 votes). You can improve the resilience of a three node replica set using three data-bearing nodes (i.e. no arbiter). Two data-bearing nodes plus an arbiter creates asymmetric failover: if a data-bearing node fails, there is still a majority for election purposes but there is no longer a second data-bearing node for replication, data redundancy, or `w:majority`

Answer (score 2):

For our special case it makes sense to have 2 arbiters. Let me explain: we have 3 data centers but 1 of these 3 data centers is not suitable to host data bearing members. That's why we host in this data center 2 arbiters for each replica set. The 3 data bearing members of the replSet are hosted in the two other data centers. If 1 of the 3 data center goes down or is not reachable due to a network partition, the replSet is still able to elect a primary, thus it's still read **and** writeable. This wouldn't be possible with only 1 or 0 arbiter. Hence, 2 arbiters may make sense.

Let's see how it may look like. Here are 2 replSets, each with 3 data bearing members and 2 arbiters in 3 data centers, whereas DC3 is the restricted data center:

```
|    |DC1  |DC2  |DC3  |
|----|-----|-----|-----|
|rs1 |m1,m2|m3   |a1,a2|
|rs2 |m1   |m2,m3|a1,a2|
```

If one data center goes down, which one would become primary?

- DC1 goes down:

  - rs1: m3
  - rs2: m2 or m3
- DC2 goes down:

  - rs1: m1 or m2
  - rs2: m1
- DC3 goes down:

  - rs1: m1,m2 or m3
  - rs2: m1,m2 or m3

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable question for the user case of 2 physical servers. One can run 1 storage member and 1 arbiter on each node for the replica set. Advantage? Well, in case of 2 replica set members you can not restart one of the storage nodes (meaning the member, not the physical server), since the other one will lose quorum and go into secondary role. But with this approach you can, since you are left with 3 voting members.

I always set the priority attribute for the storage members, so that in case of tie one always wins.

Comment: If you have 2 data-bearing nodes and 2 arbiters, the extra arbiter does not change the fault tolerance. A strict majority of 3 voting nodes is 2; a strict majority of 4 votes nodes is 3. In either case only one node can be unavailable before you lose quorum; the voting quorum is based on configured members of the replica set, not surviving members. Having an even number of voting members (2+2) allows for the possibility of a voting tie, which could cause an unexpected outage or extended election cycle if your members in different data centres disagree on the health of their peers.